# I want to fake a 4-core machine when the physical machine only has 1 CPU core

Tags: linux, cpu

I have only a 1 core CPU, but some programs need to see 4 CPUs to work correctly (although they will not use all of them).

I am using Ubuntu and my CPU info looks like this

```
ubuntu@z:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0
```

Comment: Since you are using KVM, have you tried `virsh setvcpus <vm_name> 4 --config`?

Comment: It's very rare for software to check this.  Its even more rare for software to check it when it's not actually needed.  It might be better to look for a specific solution for that software rather than generically faking more CPUs, since faking the number of CPUs may break something else.

Comment: if my memory is correct doing KVM virtual machine getting many cpu's on 2 cores machines is OK but not on mono-core machine.   your's is KVM compliant so I think at worst just try it .... with virsh